# Incremental recompile of only one file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction

In Visual Studio 2010, I have many C/C++ source files that take several minutes to compile. However, once they are compiled, I'm working only on a few files and would like to recompile them completely without deleting the compilation of the other file. I can do this if I just add a small comment to the file and it's modified, then the compiler recompiles only those files that have been modified from scratch, but I'd prefer to avoid modifying the source to do this. Is there a better way?

Basically what happens is I am cleaning up the code and eliminating issues. To do so, after every fix I recompile and test. However, when I do that, it erases the list of the issues that existed, so I am forced to add a comment line to the file I'm interested in checking to force it to recompile without cleaning the whole project.

Comment: It already works that way.  Get better feedback by mentioning the language you use.

Comment: Stating the language you are using would be a good idea. The C++ and C# compiler are very different beasts, just to take an example.

Comment: Added. I am using C/C++. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Hans: Press CTRL+SHIFT+B and you'll get a complete build. Press it again and nothing happens. I want it to rebuild a file and show me the errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on a single file in Solution Explorer and select Compile.

Comment: Doesn't work. The output says:
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)

Comment: That means there are no changes to either this file or its dependencies since the last time the file was compiled. Under those circumstances, there should be no reason to force a recompile, but you could delete the .obj file if you really, really want to recompile anyway.

Comment: My reason to force recompile is because Visual studio clears the output indicating the errors and warnings.